# ggplot2 - Set limits for only one geom

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to apply `xlim` or `ylim` to only one `geom_`?

In pseudocode it would be something like that:

```
library(tidyverse)
cars %>%
ggplot() +
geom_point(aes(...) + xlim(0, 120) + ylim(0, 30)) +
annotate(geom = "point", x = 124, y = 35)
```

Comment: You can always filter the data for one geom beforehand to limits its range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit one geom by limiting the DF of it like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(cars) +
  geom_line(aes(speed, dist)) +
  geom_point(
    data = cars %>% filter(speed > 10 & speed < 20),
    aes(speed, dist)
  )
```

[image]